# Swapping between files causes unwanted insertion of newline by vim

Tags: vimscript

I have a blank `.vimrc` file. I'm seeing some very strange behavior. Here's what happens:

1. I open a file in vim
2. I do `:split .tmp/file` and `:q`
3. I make a change to the open file and `:w`
4. I run `:e #` which brings up the alternate file opened in step 2 and then swap back to first file with `:e #` without doing anything else.
5. I run `gx`, a command from plugin I wrote (see below) that gets input from the user from vim's status bar which then passes it to a perl script. The perl script appends and writes two lines and the message to the `.tmp/file`.
6. **THE PROBLEM:** When I reopen the `.tmp/file`, there are three newlines after the last message instead of two. So somehow, vim is slapping an extra newline character into my `.tmp/file`.

Note: This problem does not happen when I do not run steps 2, 3, and 4; everything works as expected with two lines appended after each message. Here is my plugin (yeah, it's poorly written, it's my first one):

```
nnoremap gx  :call AddCommNote()<CR>

let g:Msg = ''

function! AddCommNote()
  call inputsave()
  let g:Msg = input('Make commit message: ')
  call inputrestore()
  let g:Msg = call substitute(g:Msg, '\n', '', '')
  let is_commit = 0
  call ProcessMsg(is_commit)
endfunction

function! ProcessMsg(is_commit)
  let escaped = substitute(g:Msg, "'", "'\"'\"'", "")
  let command_to_run = "add_comm_note '" . escaped . "' "
  let command_to_run = command_to_run . "'" . expand("%:p") . "' " . a:is_commit
  exec "silent:!" . command_to_run
  :redraw!
endfunction
```

I've stripped all newlines from `g:Msg` in the plugin and in the perl script. The newline is definitely coming from vim as far as I can tell. I have no idea how.

Here is the simple perl script which is in my ~/bin directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Util;

my $f = File::Util->new();
my $message = $ARGV[0];
$message =~ s/\n//g;
my $file = $ARGV[1];
my ($path) = $f->return_path($file);
my ($name) = $f->strip_path($file);
my $tmp_file = $path . '/.tmp/' . $name;
my $newlines = $f->existent($tmp_file) ? "\n\n" : '';

if ($ARGV[2] && !$message && !$newlines) {
   $message = 'this commit message is unhelpful';
}

exit if (!$newlines && !$message); #nothing to add to the commit message file

$f->write_file('file' => $tmp_file, 'mode' => 'append', 'content' => $newlines . $message);
```

Comment: I don't know if it's linked to your issue, but I'm not sure you stripped all newlines from `g:Msg` because you didn't pass the `g` flag to the `substitute()` function: `let g:Msg = call substitute(g:Msg, '\n', '', 'g')`. Also, it could help future readers if you removed from your code everything that is not related to your issue. I didn't read the code very long, but it seems that the only relevant parts are the `gx` mapping, the `AddCommNote()` function and the `ProcessMsg()` function.

Comment: But I may have missed something. In any case, the less code you show, the easier it is to find where the problem comes from. Also, it could help to reproduce the issue, if you wrote the name of the perl script (is it `add_comm_note` ?), and showed what is its contents. FWIW, when I have a weird bug, usually I create a dedicated branch with git to not mess the original code, then I delete as much code as I can until the bug disappears. Usually, once you've reached the minimum amount of code to reproduce a bug, it's easier to understand it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made the adjustment to the original question per your suggestion. I will post up perl script as well. Just to emphasize: everything works fine as long as I don't swap files in step 4. No newline is added. So I have to assume it is related to the swap of the files with `:e #`.

I should also add that every once in a while (like one out of 10 times), no extra newline gets added. So it seems like some kind of race condition going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about perl, so if the problem comes from the script, or an interaction between Vim and the script I can't help you.

That being said, for the Vim part, here's how I would do it:

```
nno gx  :<C-U>call AddCommNote()<CR>

let g:Msg = ''

fu! AddCommNote() abort
    let g:Msg = substitute(input('Make commit message: '), '\n', '', 'g')
    let is_commit = 0
    call ProcessMsg(is_commit)
endfu

fu! ProcessMsg(is_commit) abort
    echom printf('silent !add_comm_note %s %s %d',
                \   shellescape(g:Msg, 1),
                \   shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1),
                \   a:is_commit
                \ )
    redraw!
endfu
```

---

There are 2 main differences between this version and yours.

First, it adds the `g` flag to the `substitute()` function, so that all newlines are stripped and not only the first one, and it removes the `:call` token from the assignment (`:call` is only needed when you want to run the code inside a function; it's an error if you use it inside an assignment). So, these lines:

```
let g:Msg = input('Make commit message: ')
let g:Msg = call substitute(g:Msg, '\n', '', '')
```

… could be replaced with:

```
let g:Msg = substitute(input('Make commit message: '), '\n', '', 'g')
```

The second difference is the use of `shellescape()` and `printf()`. This part:

```
let escaped = substitute(g:Msg, "'", "'\"'\"'", "")
let command_to_run = "add_comm_note '" . escaped . "' "
let command_to_run = command_to_run . "'" . expand("%:p") . "' " . a:is_commit
exec "silent:!" . command_to_run
```

… could be replaced with:

```
  exe printf('silent !add_comm_note %s %s %d',
          \   shellescape(g:Msg, 1),
          \   shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1),
          \   a:is_commit
          \ )
  redraw!
```

`:execute` should execute the output of the `printf()` function.

`printf()` expects a string describing a template containing various items. Each item inside the template is preceded by a `%` sign.
Here, the template passed to `printf()` as a first argument is:

```
silent !add_comm_note %s %s %d
```

It contains 3 items `%s`, `%s`, `%d`. Each item will be replaced with the next arguments passed to `printf()`. `%s` denotes a string, while `%d` denotes a decimal number.
The next arguments passed to `printf()` are:

```
shellescape(g:Msg, 1)            the value of this expression will replace the first `%s`
shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)    the value of this expression will replace the second `%s`
a:is_commit                      the value of this expression will replace the last `%d`
```

The shell arguments that you pass to your perl script, could have special characters which have a special meaning to the shell or to Vim.
To protect them, `shellescape()` is called (protection from the shell), and `1` is passed as a second argument (protection from Vim). See `:h shellescape()` for more info.

---

If this new version doesn't work, you could replace `:exe` with `:echom`:

```
fu! ProcessMsg(is_commit) abort
  echom printf('silent !add_comm_note %s %s %d',
           \    shellescape(g:Msg, 1),
           \    shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1),
           \    a:is_commit
           \ )
  redraw!
endfu
```

After typing your mapping, `gx`, the whole command should be logged inside the message-history (see `:h :echom`). You could read it by typing `:messages`, then hit `G` to go to the bottom of the history. Maybe you could read what it looks like, and make some tweaks according to what you want the shell to execute.

---

If it doesn't help because the problem comes from an interaction between Vim and the perl script, I'll delete the answer. I just wrote this in case it have an effect on the issue.

---

Edit:

To better understand where the bug comes from, you could also use the `system()` function to capture the output of the shell command inside a global variable (e.g. `g:debug`):

```
fu! ProcessMsg(is_commit) abort
    let g:debug = system(printf('add_comm_note %s %s %d',
                \   shellescape(g:Msg, 1),
                \   shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1),
                \   a:is_commit
                \ ))
endfu
```

Then, read the output with `:echo g:debug` (and maybe post it here in your question, if you think it's relevant to the issue).

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I will study this. And actually, it looks like I might be chasing ghosts. I thought I had disabled the original `.vimrc` file when I actually hadn't. So the problem is being introduced somewhere in the `.vimrc` file. Looks like I'll have to do half splitting (comment out half the file to find the part causing the problem) until I narrow down where it is. Sigh.

Comment: @StevieD In case it helps, you don't have to comment your file, you can use the `finish` command, it's a little bit faster. In case you're interested, I briefly explained how to use it at the end of this question: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10637/6960 If this answer doesn't help, or someone has a solution for you, feel free to unaccept the answer later.

Comment: By the way, there are other vimrc files from well-known vimmers which you may find interesting: https://github.com/mhinz/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/vimrc, https://github.com/justinmk/config/blob/master/.config/nvim/init.vim, https://github.com/junegunn/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc The first one is from `mhinz` which also has a tutorial on github: https://github.com/mhinz/vim-galore

Comment: So, I basically emptied out my vimrc file and it's still happening. There is some kind of a race condition going on. It happens much more reliably if there is a long string in the message (like 20 or 30 or more characters). Very weird.

Comment: OK, actually, it was in the .vimrc file. It's this line: `nmap g  :w<CR>:e #<CR>`. If I comment that line out, I cannot make the newline show up.

Comment: Good catch! This is a recursive mapping, so when you were hitting `gx`, it's possible that Vim was replacing the `g` inside `gx` with `:w<CR>:e #<CR>`, so in the end, it's as if you were typing something like `:w<CR>:e #<CR>x`. Recursive mappings can lead to side-effects, that's why usually they are avoided. You could replace `nmap` with `nnoremap`.

Comment: Ha, i just tried that. It still happens, but far, far less frequently with `nnoremap`. I just did it 9 times and it happened only once. Maybe simply because it operates faster?

Comment: I really don't know, but maybe there are other recursive mappings inside the `vimrc`. If there was a `nmap g ...`, maybe there's a `nmap x ...`. You could try to replace all the recursive mappings with non-recursive ones (`nmap` -> `nnoremap`, `vmap` -> `vnoremap`, `imap` -> `inoremap`, ...).

Comment: I remapped it to the `;` key instead of `g` key. It still happens.

Comment: I'm going to try unloading all the other plugins except mine.

Comment: To replace the recursive mappings with non-recursive ones, you could try this substitution command: `%s/\v(\a)map/\1noremap/gc` It should ask you a confirmation before each substitution, so you could choose each time, whether you want the substitution or not.

Comment: Well, even after getting rid of all the other plugins, I still have the issue every once in a while. Very odd. Let me try your improvements for my plugin script.

Comment: OK, I added your code. Still does it, but even less frequently now. Extremely weird.

Comment: OK, so even with your code I am still having problems with all modules and entire `.vimrc` code. I will just fix this in the perl code for now with a substitution regex. But, anyway, thanks so much for your thoughtful help. I am learning a lot and you are helping minimize my frustration. Much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there are still recursive mappings inside the modules, and you would have to perform the same substitution inside those as well. By the way, I think the pattern in the previous substitution was a bit too broad and adding anchors (`\<`, `\>`) around would have been better: `:%s/\v<(\a)map>/\1noremap/gc` Anyway, to perform a substitution across several files in a single command, you would have to populate the arglist or the quickfixlist, but that's a whole other topic. If you're interested, watch the vimcasts episodes n° 41 to n°45, from this page: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/archive/